# I want to use laravel password hash algorithm in cakephp framework

Tags: laravel, authentication, cakephp-2.0, password-encryption, password-hash

I am using two frameworks in my applications: laravel and cakephp. 
I use one database for both frameworks.

I'd like to user logged-in into both application with same password.

Laravel use `salt` password hash algo. Cakephp use `DefaultPasswordHasher` algo.

I need to use add password hash algorithm in cakephp same as laravel password algorithm.

Could anyone help me with this query?
How to use same password hash algo with both frameworks?

Thank you in advance!